# How to install srpos plugin in vlc?

Tags: 14.04, vlc, plugins

I tried installing `srpos` plugin from [here](http://vlcsrposplugin.sourceforge.net/). 
But it shows the following error in the terminal when I use the command :

```
./configure && make && make install 

 make[1]: Entering directory 
/home/abhishah901/Downloads/libsrpos_plugin-0.5'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/lib/vlc/plugins'
 /bin/bash ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libsrpos_plugin.la '/usr/lib/vlc/plugins'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libsrpos_plugin.so /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/libsrpos_plugin.so
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/libsrpos_plugin.so': Permission denied
make[1]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory``/home/abhishah901/Downloads/libsrpos_plugin-0.5'
make: *** [install-am] Error 2
```

And also the plugin is not detected in the VLC Player (That's probably because of the errors I guess).

I am using 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

You have `Permission denied` error because you need to run `make install` as `sudo` (root) :

```
 ./configure
 make
 sudo make install
```

---

<s>But I strongly advise you to install this plugin using the [samrog131 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~samrog131/+ppa-packages) instead.</s>

You won't need to compile it by yourself and you will always have the up-to-date version of the plugin :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:samrog131/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc-srpos-plugin
```

Srpos Plugin package has been removed from the PPA.

Comment: So then what am I suppose to do now to make my videos play from the last position I left them from? Any help? Should I post another question for that?Help!

Comment: Have you activate the plugin ? Refer [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/07/make-vlc-automatically-save-restore.html) for how to activate plugin.

Comment: Moreover if you managed to install srpos using my answer do not hesitate to click on the grey mark beside my answer to mark it as "Valid answer" ;)